# Creating a database through an sql script and then using that database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-scripts

I have a script which uses an existing database to create tables and enter values. Now I wish to create the database through this same script and then create the tables and values which are just a copy of another database.

I have:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase

USE [MyDatabase]
....Code that creates the tables and values from another database.
```

The `USE [MyDatabase]` command is not recognized since MyDatabase does not exist anywhere yet. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, insert the [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) command in between your scripts.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase
GO
USE [MyDatabase]
```

Comment: Be careful with this. GO is _not_ part of the SQL language. It works with some tools, because those tools are configured specially to look for it... but they can be set not to look for it, or to look for something else instead.

Comment: How do you set the directory in which the database is created in?

Comment: CREATE DATABASE has syntax for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn for fun set your batch separator to `SELECT` or `FROM` :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand or even better, a co-worker's separator when you catch him away from his desk

Comment: @Joel well, yes, that's what I meant, but didn't want to catch flack if someone got caught doing that. :-)